# Thymeleaf: working with HTML entity

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template

```html
<td class="col_name" th:text="${carPriceSummary.price} + &nbsp;&euro; "></td>
```

But I got this error:

> Could not parse as expression: "${carPriceSummary.price} +  € "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

You may be better off using the utility method for currency that would include the appropriate symbol based on the locale:

`<td class="col_name" th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(carPriceSummary.price)}">[price]</td>`

but otherwise, adding the string representation would be a hacky way to do it:

`<td class="col_name" th:text="${carPriceSummary.price} + ' &euro;' ">[price]</td>`

In either case, I would recommend including a default string like `[price]` so that it can be opened directly in a browser with the `col_name` class applied.  This is a key strength to using Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `&nbsp;&euro;` is not a valid expression. You'd at least need to make sure it's recognised as a string, ie put it in quotes.

I recommend the [literal substitution](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) format

```
th:text="|${carPriceSummary.price}&nbsp;&euro; |"
```